# Angular2 - why doesn't async variable work with [hidden] directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-template

I have links that I need to hide or show based on the services to or permissions of the current user. I have these services accessible via an Observable object and was hoping to use it in my template to determine what to hide/show.

I noticed though that this works for *ngIf but not for the [hidden] directive. I can't find any info on why this is?

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <a href="" *ngIf="(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE === true">
   Save dropdown</a>

  <a href="" [hidden]="(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE === false">
   [Hidden] search</a>

  <a href="" [hidden]="hideOtherLink">
   The other link</a>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  hideOtherLink = false;
  services$: Observable<object>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.services$ = Observable.timer(2000)
      .map(() => {
        return { 
          SPECIAL_FEATURE: true,
          SPECIAL_THING: true
        }
      });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hideOtherLink = true;
    }, 2000);
  }

}
```

Comment: `*ngIf` shows the subtree if the condition true. `[hidden]` hides the subtree if the condition is true. So it looks like you should be using `*ngIf="(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE === true"`

Comment: @martin whoops. That was a typo on my part. I have this for a work project but something must be interfering with the [hidden] css perhaps

Comment: So what's the problem? The demo works as expected. `[Hidden] search` is visible because the condition results to `false` which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You got confused in your conditions there.

This one means

```
*ngIf="(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE === false"
```

> If the condition is true, then show it

While this one means

```
[hidden]="(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE === false"
```

> If the condition is true, then hide it.

They are the opposit of each other, that's why it is "not working".

**EDIT** You edited your question to set the ngIf to true, So I tested it on stack and I think I got your issue.

In your hidden condition, you test if the value of `SPECIAL_FEATURE` is equal to false.

This means

> hide the content only if the special feature variable is equal to false.

But this doesn't cover the `undefined` or `null` values, for instance, which are **falsy** values.

**[Try this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bbncn?file=app/app.component.html)** :

```
[hidden]="!(services$ | async)?.SPECIAL_FEATURE"
```

Comment: And you still have an issue ?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz to show my learnings https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8kau9

Comment: Seems like you got it :)